# Area51 allows me to vote on my own question even though it says you "can't" by clicking the RED popup box

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51

I am able to vote on my own questions on Area51 even though it says you can't vote on your own questions.

Comment: Not sure if it matters where I click inside the pop-up message but it seems to happen when I click on the top portion of the message.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you be more specific?  I'm fairly certain that even if you are seeing the vote on the page, if you refresh it won't actually be there.

Comment: Can't reproduce...

Comment: I tried it for several questions, here is the proposal I tried it on.  Unless someone else was clicking on the vote button at the exact moment I did (which is possible).

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3296/turkish-language

Check the voter ID in the tables maybe?  Refresh doesn't clear the votes, but I'll try a browser restart.

Comment: Of course, it is possible that someone else was voting at exactly the same moment.

Comment: Trying to re-produce on other proposals and it doesn't seem to be happening.  Feel free to close as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a coincidence.  Looking at the DB, I see the two followers of [that proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3296/turkish-language) voting for each other's questions at nearly the same time.  I guess you just both happened to be on at exactly the same time.